# Finding duplicates in an array using C

Tags: performance, c, programming-challenge, hash-map

I came across a [problem on LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/).
There is an input array of integers. I need to find out if there any repeating integers, then return true else false.
So, I tried using [a hashtable library available in C](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html) and wrote the code below. 
My run time is approximately 44ms.

1. How can I optimize this code?
2. Using hashtable, can I improve the logic further?

```
struct hash {
    int key;
    int value;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
};

struct hash *hashtable = NULL;

void addToHash(int key, int value)
{
  struct hash *map;
  //I am using the array elements as hash keys
  HASH_FIND_INT(hashtable, &key, map);

  if(map == NULL)
  {
    map = (struct hash*)malloc(sizeof(struct hash));
    map->key = key;
    HASH_ADD_INT(hashtable, key, map);
  }     
  map->value = value;
}   

struct hash *findInHash(int key)
{
    struct hash *h;
    HASH_FIND_INT(hashtable, &key, h);
    return h;
}

bool containsDuplicate(int* nums, int numsSize) {

    struct hash *hPtr;
    int target = 0;
    hashtable = NULL;
    if((numsSize <= 1) || (nums == 0)) return false;

    int i, index1 = 0;   

    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        /*The below statement will look if the key is already present in the 
          hashtable*/
        hPtr = findInHash(*(nums + i) - target);
        /*If the key is found already, then it look for the value of that 
        key. If the value and the current array element is same, then a 
        duplicate exist*/
        if(hPtr && hPtr->key == *(nums+i))
           return true;
        addToHash(*(nums + i), i);
    }
    struct hash *temp;
    HASH_ITER(hh, hashtable, hPtr, temp) {free(hPtr);}
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "How can I optimize this code?" be specific. optimize for speed, memory usage, code footprint, clarity, ...?

Comment: Optimize for speed.

Comment: I'm assuming `HASH_FIND_INT`, `HASH_ITER` are library calls. But did you copy and paste the entire library source code into the Leetcode text input? Surely, this is bringing a gun to a knife fight. There are numerous `qsort` solutions that run 12ms with just a few lines of code. I don't think Leetcode runs enough tests for speed to matter on this challenge. Also, if you're using someone's library as a client, you're pretty much tied down to their implementation. More clarification about what you're trying to achieve would be helpful here.

Comment: @ggorlen, not really. Leetcode suggests programmers to use that library for hashtable. I know we can solve this with qsort. But since i am learning hashtables, I want to know how else can I optimize this code.

Comment: How does this teach you about hash tables? You loaded the library, called their functions and it works--there's no hashing algorithm here. All of the potential for optimization is in the library code that's not included in this post.

Comment: My first step it learn how to use an existing thing. Currently, I am writing my own hash table as well which I will post here for review this week. Before that I want to get clarity with few questions about using an existing one.

Comment: As @ggorlen mentioned a hash table will be overkill for this solution. Since a hash table will involve allocating small bits of memory many times it is also not going to perform as well as something using an array possibly created by `calloc()` once. Each time the algorithm adds a node it will call a system routine to allocate the memory to the process, that means the program itself will be swapped out while the memory is being allocated.

Comment: You can improve this question by including the description of the problem statement from LeetCode and including the hash table functions, currently there isn't enough code here to review.